# Using cache or temporary tables for optimising a query with many union all

Tags: oracle

I need to query many tables in A Oracle database in a single query for a typeahead function, which means I need to query for each keypress on a homepage.

```
select * from 
(select * from table1
 union all
 select * from table2
 union all
 select * from table3
 union all
 select * from table4
) 
 where colume_name like '%xxx%'
```

All the union will result in a dataset of around 300000 records.

Is there anyway, this query can be optimized, so Oracle somehow keep the united dataset in a cache or temporary table that can be used for the next keypress?

Answer (score 0):

As you said - you could create a (global) temporary table with `on commit preserve rows` option, store the result in there and use data during that session.